# Switch between UIImages in UICollectionView cells that contain UIImageViews

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview

I have a UICollectionView which is filled with the user's images straight from the photo library.

If the user clicks the image after picking it from the library, the main images switches to the selected image.

[image: how it looks]

Each cell contains a UIImageView.

I've tried to switch them using this code:

```
let cell = self.imageUICV.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: self.numOfCellSelected, section: 0)) as! AddImageCollectionViewCell
let mainCell = self.imageUICV.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: self.numOfCellSelected, section: 0)) as! AddImageCollectionViewCell
guard let mainImage = mainCell.itemImageUIImage.image?.cgImage?.copy() else {
    return
}
let newMainImage = UIImage(cgImage: mainImage, scale: mainCell.itemImageUIImage.image!.scale, orientation: mainCell.itemImageUIImage.image!.imageOrientation)
guard let cellImage = cell.itemImageUIImage.image?.cgImage?.copy() else {
    return
}
let newCellImage = UIImage(cgImage: cellImage, scale: cell.itemImageUIImage.image!.scale, orientation: cell.itemImageUIImage.image!.imageOrientation)
self.imagePlaceholderArray[self.numOfCellSelected] = newMainImage
self.imagePlaceholderArray[0] = newCellImage
self.imageUICV.reloadData()
```

However, only the main image changed, whilst the the images in the smaller cells stayed the same.

Comment: What is your question? What problem are you having with the code you posted?

Comment: that code only changes the main cell image, the smaller cells stay the same

Comment: can't you just keep an array with `[UIImages]` and newly selected image to the top of that array then just simply reload your collection view.

Comment: the code has [imagePlaceholderArray] which is of type [UIImage], afterwards .reloadData() which reloads the collection view. still the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading cells at specific indexes for which you want to change the image or reload all after setting image.